# Not yet another question about truecrypt on usb!

Tags: usb, truecrypt

everybody,

After reading a few topics on this forum, and the Truecrypt documentation, I still can't understand how to achieve my objective:

To encrypt data on a usb device and use it on any computer where:

1. they don't have Truecrypt installed
2. I don't have admin privileges (I do have admin privileges on my own computer, which I am trying to use to create such volume/file).

After creating an encrypted file container on the usb, I have copied the Truecrypt executable file on it. Of course, I cannot run it from another computer, as I do not have admin privileges.

On the Truecrypt documentation they talk about using **Tools** --> **Traveler Disk Setup** which I do not seem able to find anywhere when launching the program.

Is there any way to achieve my objective?

Thanks,

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truecrypt handles the mounting of encrypted/hidden volumes using its own executable program.  If you do not have sufficient privileges on the computer, and truecrypt is not installed, it is not possible to decrypt the drive within that environment.

Quick workaround would be to boot the target computer with another live usb containing pre-installed truecrypt. That way you could decrypt your encrypted usb drive and copy any files over to the target system and vice-versa.

This [truecrypt website](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/non-admin-users) has information regarding why it can not run without administrator privileges. You can run the program in portable mode (meaning no installation is necessary) however you will not be able to run it without being an administrator, as documented [here](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/truecrypt-portable).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to look for a different program I guess then.